# Virtual box error

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox

I download virtual box 5.1.22, create new virtual machine and cant lauch machine.

```
    The virtual machine 'Debian' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1). More details may be available in 'C:\Users\Администратор\VirtualBox VMs\Debian\Logs\VBoxHardening.log'.


Error code: 
E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: 
MachineWrap
Interface: 
IMachine {b2547866-a0a1-4391-8b86-6952d82efaa0}
```

VBoxHardening.log last strings:

```
5cc.d74: supR3HardenedWinVerifyCacheProcessImportTodos: Processing 'user32.dll'...
5cc.d74: supR3HardenedWinVerifyCacheProcessImportTodos: 'user32.dll' -> '\Device\HarddiskVolume4\Windows\System32\user32.dll' [rcNtRedir=0xc0150008]
5cc.d74: supR3HardenedWinVerifyCacheProcessImportTodos: Processing 'ole32.dll'...
5cc.d74: supR3HardenedWinVerifyCacheProcessImportTodos: 'ole32.dll' -> '\Device\HarddiskVolume4\Windows\System32\ole32.dll' [rcNtRedir=0xc0150008]
5cc.d74: supR3HardenedScreenImage/Imports: cache hit (VINF_SUCCESS) on \Device\HarddiskVolume4\Windows\System32\ole32.dll
5cc.d74: supR3HardenedWinVerifyCacheProcessImportTodos: Processing 'gdi32.dll'...
5cc.d74: supR3HardenedWinVerifyCacheProcessImportTodos: 'gdi32.dll' -> '\Device\HarddiskVolume4\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll' [rcNtRedir=0xc0150008]
5cc.d74: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: pName=C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\platforms\qwindows.dll (rcNtResolve=0xc0150008) *pfFlags=0x0 pwszSearchPath=00000000008a4af0:C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox;C:\Windows\system32 [calling]
5cc.d74: supR3HardenedScreenImage/NtCreateSection: cache hit (VINF_SUCCESS) on \Device\HarddiskVolume4\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\platforms\qwindows.dll
5cc.d74: supR3HardenedDllNotificationCallback: load   000007feeb8c0000 LB 0x0012e000 C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\platforms\qwindows.dll [fFlags=0x0]
5cc.d74: supR3HardenedScreenImage/LdrLoadDll: cache hit (VINF_SUCCESS) on \Device\HarddiskVolume4\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\platforms\qwindows.dll
5cc.d74: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: returns rcNt=0x0 hMod=000007feeb8c0000 'C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\platforms\qwindows.dll'
5cc.d74: supR3HardenedScreenImage/LdrLoadDll: cache hit (VINF_SUCCESS) on \Device\HarddiskVolume4\Windows\System32\cryptbase.dll
5cc.d74: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: pName=C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTBASE.dll (Input=CRYPTBASE.dll, rcNtResolve=0xc0150008) *pfFlags=0x0 pwszSearchPath=00000000008a4af0:C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox;C:\Windows\system32 [calling]
5cc.d74: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: returns rcNt=0x0 hMod=000007fefc020000 'C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTBASE.dll'
760.654: supR3HardNtChildWaitFor[2]: Quitting: ExitCode=0x1 (rcNtWait=0x0, rcNt1=0x0, rcNt2=0x103, rcNt3=0x103, 2051 ms, the end);
1b14.c7c: supR3HardNtChildWaitFor[1]: Quitting: ExitCode=0x1 (rcNtWait=0x0, rcNt1=0x0, rcNt2=0x103, rcNt3=0x103, 2662 ms, the end);
```

Answer (score 0):

- Installed the latest update from Microsoft. [Click Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/3024777)
- Did System Reboot?.
- Uninstalled the Oracle VM VirtualBox.
- Installed it
  again after a second Reboot.

Comment: Im arleady do it